# LabVIEW: Correct way to control loop execution from an event structure

Tags: event-handling, labview, program-flow

The program used has a a few control buttons (start, pause, stop, close) that are supposed to control the execution of a subVI test program. This is mainly a loop doing a certain task.

The question is: what is the proper approach to control the program flow (while loop) from the event structure? E.g. a start button press is supposed to start the flow - can I just wire this to the while loop? Wouldn't that mean polling the value? Or would it be passed only after the event is fired?

So far I have a loop for the events (multiple button value changes) and one other loop for the test program:

[image]

I assume something like the Queued Message Handler can be used for that? How can I achieve that the current loop run is stopped?

Comment: Does the sub-VI continuously work (e.g. blocking while waiting for data from external devices) or does it short bursts of work on a button click or timeout?

Comment: The sub-VI is a rather long task, running a test including reading and writing analog ports - this test is likely to run for hours/days and should be able to be aborted by a button click.

Comment: Okay, in that case, kosist's answer is probably the best choice. If you can split it into small operations that don't block for very long, a state machine running in the event loop (controlling the timeout to get background work done) would be simpler but that sounds unsuitable for what you describe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Event-driven producer-consumer pattern.

Long story short: producer loop handles user events (like button press), and sends commands to consumer loop. Usually, communication between loops is done via queues. Queue sends cluster, which consists of state (which is either string or enum data type, [LabVIEW queued state machine: enum or string?](https://kosist.org/2016/11/labview-queued-state-machine-enum-or-string/)) and data (which is variant data type).

Consumer loop enqueues messages from the queue, and based on state runs corresponding logic. Consumer loop has case structure, and selector is state value from the queue.

There is a lot of different guides on the internet. Great overview is this presentation [Introduction to LabVIEW Design Patterns](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/labview_design_patterns.pdf), also you could check this one [Event-driven producer-consumer state machine](https://learn-cf.ni.com/teach/riodevguide/code/pc_producer-consumer-state-machine.html), or even video [LabVIEW code: Event-driven producer-consumer state machine (walk-through)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-EmDOQCcIc), etc.

Comment: Thanks! I will dig into that! One question for the consumer loop logic: am I able to stop it in the middle of a loop iteration?
(The background is that I occasionally want to stop the test (being run in the consumer loop) while it is in the middle of the process)

Comment: @femto-code sure you can, but it depends on the consumer's loop implementation. If your state machine will have some long-running process (like inner while loop or something), then when queue is destroyed/or you send Stop message) will be caught only on the next iteration of outer while loop.

Comment: Okay, I see - in my case there is indeed a long-running process that might have to be stopped at some point. What would be the approach to stop the inner while loop early? Just wire the stop criterion?

Comment: Does your long-running process is wrapped into while loop? If so, you could use global variable, functional global variable or notifier to monitor stop signal. It is hard to tell without code what exactly could suit you the most.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, it is wrapped into a while loop. It does continuous analog input/output and calculations to adjust testing parameters. It consists of a number of N predefined cycles (running loop N times) and some post-processing in each iteration. However, the user might want to pause (or cancel) this process, that means: ending the consumer loop process code earlier! I will try your suggestion with a variable to monitor.

Comment: In order to understand the principle: what happens in general if the queue gets a new element but the consumer loop is still processing a foregone element?

Comment: @femto-code queue has FIFO buffer. So it will keep adding elements to the end of the queue. Regarding your above mentioned description of your process - even such process could be separated into several states of the state machine. For example, imagine that you need to execute N cycles of some procedure. One way - is to have For Loop, and run it N times in one state. But the other way - is to have counter for that process, and state will execute cycle once. Then go to another state -> check and increase counter -> decide to continue or stop.

Comment: I don't see yet why I have to use a queue - I am not planning to execute a whole sequence of commands. I just want to control the execution of a loop. This loop should optimally check in every iteration for stop signals. I will check what I can do with notifiers.

Comment: @femto-code programming patters are proofed by time. They help to solve common tasks easier. Understanding might come or not with time why it is important to use them. I saw applications with one while loop, case structure with number selectors, and bunch of wires going there and back - such applications were working, but it was pain to maintain them with time. Play around, check different approaches - understanding will come with practice only.